# Why are points of zero Gaussian curvature called parabolic?

Tags: curvature

The sign of the Gaussian curvature can be used to classify points as *elliptic*, *hyperbolic*, and *parabolic*. Wikipedia has this image with example surfaces:

[image: From left to right: a surface of negative Gaussian curvature (hyperboloid), a surface of zero Gaussian curvature (cylinder), and a surface of positive Gaussian curvature (sphere).]

I see how a hyperboloid surface has hyperbolic points, and respectively a sphere or ellipsoid has elliptic points. So these are aptly named.

But why are points with zero Gaussian curvature named parabolic, not something like cylindrical or conical?
Especially, a paraboloid has positive curvature.

[image: Paraboloid of revolution]

Comment: A way to look at it is that the differential of the gauss map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map has an eigenvalue that is zero in one of the directions on the cylinder.  However, I look forward to a post explaining why that is called "parabolic".  Likewise, why is the heat equation "parabolic".

Comment: A [cylindrical paraboloid](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/vnx/math251/gifstuff/parabolic_cylinder.gif) has zero Gaussian curvature.

Comment: I see. But still, that itself is called *cylindrical*, which seems to be the deciding part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nomenclature is from origin of conics categorization . Among the conics  eccentricity $\epsilon$ for a hyperbola, parabola and ellipse are $ \gt 1, = 1, \lt 1 $ respectively. In its categorizing work sign of double or Gauss curvature relates to $ (1- \epsilon). $

In the equation of conic( two dimensions) there is already an indicator of things to come when it would be embedded in 3-space.   For $ a x^2 + 2 h x y + by^2 $ + linear  terms =0, then the sign of invariant $ a \cdot b - h^2 $ also decides to which of the three types the conic under consideration belongs.

Accordingly in $ \mathbb R^{2}$ say for a surface in Monge form $ z= f(x,y), K= (r \cdot t - s^2)/(1+p^2+q^2)^2 $ (partial derivatives of z) decides sign of Gauss curvature K, i.e., to which of the three types you have shown the surface belongs.

EDIT 1:

Also if a reputed mathematician had called it that way and it stuck,the matter of distinguishing between the three was settled temporarily.

Having said the above in defense of what I believe is the *staus quo ante* I am in agreement with the OP about inappropriateness of the *parabolic* appellation of $ K=0 $ flat surfaces.

When a paraboloid  is and quite apparently looks $K >0$ there is no need to cling on to any historical reasons. In line with the view of OP  I too like to see it changed to  ***developable*** or  ***flat***, but not further retain  ***parabolic.***